# Make pi connect to wifi without screen

Tags: wifi, ssh, sd-card

I have a raspberry pi, and I don't have a screen. I can plug my pi's sdcard into my laptop and access the files, so is there a way I can  install openssh by adding some files to the sdcard on my laptop and make it so when it boots up it connects to the wifi?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install anything. Assuming you are using Raspbian it is already installed, however on recent releases it is disabled for security reasons.

There is a shortcut, creating a file `ssh` on the boot partition, but this ONLY works on initial boot. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/

Your remaining option is to enable using `raspi-config`